# Nonlinear system of 2 equations with 2 unknowns involving cosine and exponential functions

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

How many solutions do exist for this System of equations with $x,y \in (0,1)$

\begin{align*} 
\sqrt3 \cdot x = \cos(xy)\\ 
e^{-xy} = 2y\\ 
\end{align*}

Comment: Where ar you blocked ? What have you tried ? A hint : set $z:=xy$.

Comment: $\cos(1) \le \cos(xy) \le 1$ in this range, so we know that solutions only could exists for $\cos(1)/\sqrt{3}\le x \le \frac{1}{3} $. You can restrict further by plugging $y = 1 $ with these boundaries into $\cos(xy)$ and manipulating. You can do similar constrictions on $y$ using the second equation. Intermediate value theorem may prove useful too

Comment: I can't seem to edit my comment, so take note that with your open interval, my $\le$ signs should be $<$ signs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We get $2\sqrt3 \cdot x y=\cos(xy)e^{-xy}$, hence $2\sqrt3 \cdot x ye^{xy}-\cos(xy)=0$

For $t \in [0,1]$ let $f(t)=2\sqrt3 te^{t}-\cos(t)$. Then we have:

$f(0)=-1$, $f(1)>0$ and $f$ is strictly increasing. Hence there is exactly one $t \in (0,1)$ such that $f(t)=0$.

Can you proceed ?

Comment: This really helped me understand the equation thank you